# Incorrect matplotlib plot using Python 2.7.15 but not when using 2.7.10

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Plotted in Python 2.7.10]

[image: Plotted in Python 2.7.15]

Notice how the plot is shifting to the left in the bottom plot.  Both plots were made with the exact same input data and same Python script, but plotted on different computers with different versions of Python.  Can anyone suggest where I might find the culprit?  The top plot is correct, bottom is not.

Comment: What is your matplotlib version?

Comment: Responded as comment in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the matplotlib documentation of `bar`

[Version 1.3.1](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)

> `align` : [‘edge’ | ‘center’], optional, **default: ‘edge’**

[Version 2.2.3](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)

> `align` : {'center', 'edge'}, optional, **default: 'center'**

Use `align="edge"` to obtain the first image in both versions. Use `align="center"` to obtain the second image in both versions.

Comment: Both answers below are correct.  I am not sure whose to accept. Technically importanceofbeingernest is more correct because of the use of "edge" instead of "right" in @jwalton3141's answer.  But in principal both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielLabbe has suggested this is most likely an issue with matplotlib versions. You can check your version of matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.__version__
```

If you have sudo / administrative rights, you'll want to update matplotlib on one of your machines so they both run the same version. If you can't do this, explicitly specifying the `align` argument in `plt.hist` might help, eg.

```py
plt.hist(my_data, align='right')
```

Comment: Good plot matplotlib version is 1.3.1 and incorrect plot version is 2.2.3.  Huge difference.  I will hold off on updating my older version until I figure out how to fix the script.

Comment: In that case you should try specifying ```align='right'``` or ```align='left'``` in the call to ```plt.hist``` when plotting in version 2.2.3. By default ```align='mid'``` in 2.2.3, which is what you're seeing